# Problem with OpenAI and PHP Client - Why?

Tags: php, openai-api

https://github.com/openai-php/client

For my project, I want to send prompt and get answer, I only copied the code on the GitHub

```php
$yourApiKey = getenv('YOUR_API_KEY');
$client = OpenAI::client($yourApiKey);

$result = $client->completions()->create([
    'model' => 'text-davinci-003',
    'prompt' => 'PHP is',
]);

echo $result['choices'][0]['text'];
```

And get a new api key from https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys

[image]

And I get this error every time,

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OpenAI\Exceptions\ErrorException: You didn't provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in an Authorization header using Bearer auth (i.e. Authorization: Bearer YOUR_KEY), or as the password field (with blank username) if you're accessing the API from your browser and are prompted for a username and password. You can obtain an API key from https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys. in /Users/-----/Sites/rge/vendor/openai-php/client/src/Transporters/HttpTransporter.php:61

I don't know why, I tried to create another new key, 3 times, but nothing seems to work..

Comment: What did you do with the API key once you got it?

Comment: Have you checked that `getenv('YOUR_API_KEY')` fetches what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Organization name/ID at:

https://platform.openai.com/account/org-settings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need like as

$yourApiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

Comment: https://www.php.net/getenv is a perfectly acceptable way of getting the API key, *as long as OP has set the environment variable corretly*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).